# React — onClick in component instance?

Tags: reactjs, onclick

I have a `<button>` element inside a `<BtnComponent />` (which is inside another component) and I'm trying to handle the click like this:

**The BtnContainer.js parent component:**

```
import React from 'react';
import Btn from './Btn';


var BtnContainer = React.createClass({

  handleClick() {
    alert('hello');
  },
  render() {
    return (
      <div id="container">
        <Btn onClick={this.handleClick} />
      </div>
    )
  }
});

module.exports = BtnContainer;
```

**Here is the Btn.js component.**

```
import React from 'react';

const Btn = () => (
  <button className="btn">Click</button>
);

export default Btn;
```

I tried placing the onClick in the actual button element too but got an error.

Thoughts?

Comment: You need to pass the prop onClick prop to the actual button.

Comment: I added my Btn.js component... not sure how to form the syntax.

Comment: you need to add a separate "onClick" event on the actual button html - and in the brackets call this.props.onClick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

**BtnContainer.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import Btn from './Btn';


var BtnContainer = React.createClass({

  handleClick() {
    alert('hello');
  },
  render() {
    return (
      <div id="container">
        <Btn onClick={this.handleClick} />
      </div>
    )
  }
});

module.exports = BtnContainer;
```

**Btn.js**

```
import React from 'react';

const Btn = ({ onClick }) => (
  <button onClick={onClick} className="btn">Click</button>
);

export default Btn;
```

Comment: This works. How would I amend it to toggle a class on the button element? Would I use setFilter? I am basically creating a Favorite heart button that toggles the classes btn-fav and btn-notfav when you click it.